# Make a 1 to 1 multi-field SQL join where only some of the values match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a table that will be used as a conversion chart. I aim to make a simple join with this conversion table on multiple fields (8 in my case), and get a result. I will try to simplify the examples as much as I can because the original chart is a 40x10 matrix.

Let's say that I have these two (I know they don't make much sense and have bad design but they are just examples):

```
supply_conversion_chart
---
supply (integer)
customer_id (integer)
product_id (integer)
size (varchar)
purchase_type (varchar)
```

```
purchases
---
customer_id (integer)
product_id (integer)
size (varchar)
purchase_type (varchar)
```

and conversion chart would look something like this:

```
| supply | customer_id  | product_id | size     | purchase_type |
|--------|--------------|------------|----------|---------------|
| 100    | 1            | anything   | anything | online        |
| 101    | 1            | anything   | anything | offline       |
| 102    | other than 1 | anything   | anything | online        |
| 103    | 1            | 5          | XXL      | online        |
```

The main goal was to get an exact `supply` value by simply doing a join by doing something like:

```sql
SELECT supply
FROM purchases p
         JOIN supply_conversion_chart scc ON
        p.customer_id = scc.customer_id AND
        p.product_id = scc.product_id AND
        p.size = scc.size AND
        p.purchase_type = scc.purchase_type;
```

Let's say that these are the records on `purchases` table:

```
| customer_id | product_id | size | purchase_type |
|-------------|------------|------|---------------|
| 1           | 3          | M    | online        |
| 1           | 5          | S    | offline       |
| 12345       | 4          | XL   | online        |
| 1           | 5          | XXL  | online        |
| 4353        | null       | M    | online        |
```

I would expect first record's supply value to be `101`, second record's to be `102`, third `102`, fourth `103`, and fifth to be `102`. However, as far as I know, SQL won't be able to do a proper join on all of these records except the fourth one, which is fully matching with supply `103` on `supply_conversion_chart` table. I don't know if it is possible in the first place to do a join using multiple fields when some of those fields are not fully matching.

My approach is probably faulty and there are better ways to get the results I am trying to achieve but I don't even know where to start. What should I do?
The original chart is much bigger that the provided example, and that I will be doing a join on 8 different fields.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is a lateral join:

```
select p.*, scc.*
from purchases p left join lateral
     (select scc.*
      from supply_conversion_chart scc
      where (scc.customer_id = p.customer_id or scc.customer_id is null) and
            (scc.product_id = p.product_id or scc. product_id is null) and
            (scc.size = p.size or scc.size is null) and
            (scc.purchase_type = p.purchase_type or scc.purchase_type is null) 
      order by ( (scc.customer_id = p.customer_id)::int +
                 (scc.product_id = p.product_id)::int
                 (scc.size = p.size)::int
                 (scc.purchase_type = p.purchase_type)::int
               ) desc
      limit 1
     ) scc;
```

Note:  This represents "everything" as `NULL`.  It doesn't have special logic for "customer other than 1".  However, it does show you how to implement basically what you are trying to do.